# SQL: EXCEPT Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

Here is a basic example of what I am trying to achieve:

```
create table #testing (
     tab varchar(max), a int, b int, c int )

insert into #testing VALUES ('x',1, 2, 3)
insert into #testing VALUES ('y',1, 2, 3)  
insert into #testing VALUES ('x', 4, 5, 6)  

select * from #testing
```

Which will Produce the table:

```
 tab     a    b    c
-----------------------
  x      1    2    3
  y      1    2    3
  x      4    5    6
```

I then want to compare rows on 'tab' based on the values of a,b,c:

```
select a,b,c from #testing where tab = 'x'
except
select a,b,c from #testing where tab= 'y'
```

Which gives me the answer I was expecting:

```
a    b    c
------------
4    5    6
```

However I want to also include the Tab column in my resultset, so I want somthing like this:

```
 Select tab,a,b,c from #testing where ????
            (select a,b,c from #testing where tab = 'x'
             except
             select a,b,c from #testing where tab= 'y')
```

How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `not exists`:

```
select a.*
from #testing a
where a.tab = 'x' 
      and not exists (
                       select * 
                       from #testing t 
                       where t.a = a.a and t.b = a.b and t.c = a.c and t.tab = 'y'
                     )
```

**And here you get SQL Fiddle demo: [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/335b2/2)**

Answer (score 1):

Although the answer from @gzaxx does produce a correct result for this test data, the more generalized version is below, where I left 'x' and 'y' out of the statements.

```
select a.*
from #testing a
where not exists (
                   select * 
                   from #testing t 
                   where t.a = a.a and t.b = a.b and t.c = a.c and t.tab <> a.tab
                 )
```

Answer (score 1):

Please Try it

```
 with cte as 
 (
 select *,rn = ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION by tab order by tab)from #testing 
 )
 select tab,a,b,c from cte where rn>1
```